# Elastic Search and "sub queries"

Tags: subquery, elasticsearch

Can you perform a subquery in Elastic Search?

I am finding a list of documents (usually about 5-20 documents). For each of the documents I'd like to perform a search to come up with some custom fields for them.

Each document is a property, and, I want to analyze surrounding properties for each property found in order to evaluate the average price of properties around it.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps there is a way to use nesting for this?

Comment: No, you can't use sub-queries.  Whether nested will fork for you or not depends on exactly what you're trying to achieve.  Perhaps expand the question with some example data?

Comment: Take a look at the nested query page on the reference guide
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html

Answer (score 3):

No, Elastic Search doesn't support subqueries.

You should be able to do this with an IDs query:
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/ids-query.html

Comment: can you update the link? it redirects to the homepage now