# Elasticsearch and aggregation of subqueries

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I know that elasticsearch allows [sub-aggregations](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html#_structuring_aggregations) (ie. nested aggregation), however I would like to apply aggregation on the result of "first" aggregation (or in generic any query - aggregation or not).

Concrete example: I log events about user actions (for simplicity I have documents with `user_id` and `action`). I can make a query that counts number of actions executed by each user. However I would like to find out percentage (or count) of "active users" (e.g. users that have executed more than 10 actions). Ideal result would be a [histogram](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-histogram-aggregation.html) over all users showing how active the users are.

Is there a way how to create such query? Or is there any other approach I can take other than store aggregated results of subquery and compute the histogram out of that?

Note: I have seen [Elastic Search and "sub queries"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808832/elastic-search-and-sub-queries) question, but it was about something else and it is over one and half year old and elasticsearch is being actively developed.

Additionally it seems that in version 1.4 there will be available scripted metric aggregation, but anyway that would require to store counter for every user until reduce phase. And some "approximate solution" is good for me - similar to what ES uses [internally for its aggregations](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_document_counts_are_approximate).

Comment: pretty sure the answer is that you can't aggregate on the results of an aggregation currently (i've wanted that for other reasons and haven't found a way to do it) -- +1 on the question to see if anyone else a good idea

Answer (score 2):

Here is the query I have used, notice the "min_doc_count" in the aggregation.

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "and": [
          { "term" : { "name": "did x" } },
          { "range": { "created_at": { "gte": "now-7d", "lte": "now" } } }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "my_agg": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "user_id",
        "min_doc_count": 10,
        "size": 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This query returns the list of buckets (users) with more than 9 events in the specified time period. Just 'count' results to get the number of active users.

I have tested this approach with thousands of events and it works well. At a certain scale you will have to use Hadoop.